# Splitting dataframe and saving to txt files

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as such:

```
  Histogram           DN     Npts    Total   Percent   Acc Pct
  Band 1       -0.054741        1        1    0.0250    0.0250
  Bin=0.00233  -0.052404        0        1    0.0000    0.0250
               -0.050067        0        1    0.0000    0.0250
               -0.047730        0        1    0.0000    0.0250
               -0.045393        0        1    0.0000    0.0250
               -0.043056        0        1    0.0000    0.0250
               -0.040719        0        1    0.0000    0.0250
  Histogram           DN     Npts    Total   Percent   Acc Pct
  Band 2        0.000000      346      346    9.5186    9.5186
  Bin=0.00203   0.002038        0      346    0.0000    9.5186
                0.004076        0      346    0.0000    9.5186
                0.006114        0      346    0.0000    9.5186
                0.008152        0      346    0.0000    9.5186
                0.010189        0      346    0.0000    9.5186
                0.012227        0      346    0.0000    9.5186
```

and I want to split this based on when the word Histogram occurs (in this case every 8 lines).  I could split it like this:

```
np.array_split(df,8)
```

but if there is a way to do it on the keyword I would prefer it. I then want to save each split into its own textfile.  Is there a way to do this?

`df.head().to_json()` returns:

```
{"Histogram  ":{"0":"Band 1     ","1":"Bin=0.00233","2":"           ","3":"           ","4":"           "},"       DN":{"0":"-0.054741","1":"-0.052404","2":"-0.050067","3":"-0.047730","4":"-0.045393"},"   Npts":{"0":"      1","1":"      0","2":"      0","3":"      0","4":"      0"},"  Total":{"0":"      1","1":"      1","2":"      1","3":"      1","4":"      1"}," Percent":{"0":"  0.0250","1":"  0.0000","2":"  0.0000","3":"  0.0000","4":"  0.0000"}," Acc Pct":{"0":"  0.0250","1":"  0.0250","2":"  0.0250","3":"  0.0250","4":"  0.0250"}}
```

Comment: Do  you have this data as text? If yes its easy

Comment: Yes this data originally comes from a text file.

Comment: be careful, if you keep deleting/reposting [the same question (10k only)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32895347/splitting-pandas-dataframe-and-then-performing-operations-on-the-split-data) you'll automatically be question-banned.

Comment: sorry, I am trying to find variations on ways to do this, and since I couldn't figure out another way I figured saving everything to text and then binning might work, so this is actually slightly different.

Comment: Could you read all the lines in to memory, loop though the lines and use something like "if Histogram in line:"

Comment: @StefanoPotter it's all automatic, if you delete too many posts. As I said on the original: is this your DataFrame, it doesn't look like a DataFrame, can you post the output of df.to_json()

Comment: The easiest thing from this text is to check if "histogramm" is in Line

Comment: @AndyHayden The real file is thousands of rows long, so I can't post it all, but when I get back on my computer with the data I will post part of it again.

Comment: @StefanoPotter just posting the first 5 rows is useful, e.g. df.head().to_json() OR pull out a few of the interesting rows.

Comment: @AndyHayden I added it to post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should normalize your column names, at the moment they contain spaces (this explains the KeyError you saw earlier):

```
In [11]: df1.columns
Out[11]:
Index(['       DN', '   Npts', '  Total', ' Acc Pct', ' Percent', 'Histogram  '], dtype='object')

In [12]: df1.columns.map(lambda x: x.strip())
Out[12]: array(['DN', 'Npts', 'Total', 'Acc Pct', 'Percent', 'Histogram'], dtype=object)

In [13]: df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: x.strip())
```

To group by the Band, I'd use cumsum:

```
In [14]: df1  # similar to your example
Out[14]:
         DN  Npts  Total  Acc Pct  Percent    Histogram
0 -0.054741     1      1    0.025    0.025  Band 1
1 -0.052404     0      1    0.025    0.000  Bin=0.00233
2 -0.050067     0      1    0.025    0.000
3 -0.047730     0      1    0.025    0.000
4 -0.045393     0      1    0.025    0.000
5 -0.054741     1      1    0.025    0.025  Band 2
6 -0.052404     0      1    0.025    0.000  Bin=0.00233
7 -0.050067     0      1    0.025    0.000
8 -0.047730     0      1    0.025    0.000
9 -0.045393     0      1    0.025    0.000

In [15]: df1["Histogram"].str.startswith("Band").cumsum()
Out[15]:
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    2
9    2
Name: Histogram, dtype: int64
```

You can use this to groupby (which is how you want to split):

```
In [16]: g = df1.groupby(df1["Histogram"].str.startswith("Band").cumsum())
```

Now you can extract/clean at your leisure:

```
In [21]: g.get_group(1)
Out[21]:
         DN  Npts  Total  Acc Pct  Percent    Histogram
0 -0.054741     1      1    0.025    0.025  Band 1
1 -0.052404     0      1    0.025    0.000  Bin=0.00233
2 -0.050067     0      1    0.025    0.000
3 -0.047730     0      1    0.025    0.000
4 -0.045393     0      1    0.025    0.000

In [22]: [x for _, x in g]
Out[22]:
[         DN  Npts  Total  Acc Pct  Percent    Histogram
 0 -0.054741     1      1    0.025    0.025  Band 1
 1 -0.052404     0      1    0.025    0.000  Bin=0.00233
 2 -0.050067     0      1    0.025    0.000
 3 -0.047730     0      1    0.025    0.000
 4 -0.045393     0      1    0.025    0.000             ,
          DN  Npts  Total  Acc Pct  Percent    Histogram
 5 -0.054741     1      1    0.025    0.025  Band 2
 6 -0.052404     0      1    0.025    0.000  Bin=0.00233
 7 -0.050067     0      1    0.025    0.000
 8 -0.047730     0      1    0.025    0.000
 9 -0.045393     0      1    0.025    0.000             ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will filter the dataframe txt and create new txt files for the historgram:

```
count = 1
# used in the naming of the new txt files

txtFile = "his.txt"
# histogram text file

splitTxt = " Histogram           DN     Npts    Total   Percent   Acc Pct"
# string used to split the lines of code into sections/blocks

with open(txtFile,"r") as myResults:

   blocks = myResults.read()

for contents in blocks.split(splitTxt)[1:]:

    lines = contents.split('\n')

    with open('Results_{}.txt'.format(count), 'w') as op:

        op.writelines('{}'.format(splitTxt))

        for i in range(8):

            op.writelines('{}\n'.format(lines[i]))

    count = count + 1
```